# Building an axiomatic theory

Tags: logic

I am using an expert system inferring some logical rules on a knowledge base to produce some new statements. I would like to formalize the logical mechanisms used by the inference engine. As a novice in the logic field, I am not sure of how to do it. After some researches, I come to the conclusion that what I am trying to do is building an axiomatic theory (defining a set of axioms and derives some theorems from them).

So my question is : How to build such an axiomatic theory ? As this is quite a vast question, I have tried to answer it myself, can you confirm me that I am doing it right ?

It appears to me that I need a whole formal system composed of :

- A syntax : an alphabet and some grammar rules that defines how to build formulas
- A deductive system : some axioms and some inference rules
- A semantic : a domain of discourse and an interpretation of the alphabet over this domain

*Illustration on a factory example :*

- Syntax : first order logic alphabet and grammar
- Deductive system : an Hilbert system without logical axiom & modus ponens rule of inference & some domain specific axioms (see below)
- Semantic : all things of the word as a domain of discourse & an interpretation linked to this use-case (see below)

Let's $D$ denote the domain of discourse and let's $E, P, O \subset D$ respectively denotes the set of all employees, the set of all products and the set of all orders of the factory.

Here are some predicates :

- isEmployee(-) : the fact of being an employee that is interpreted by the set $E \subset D$ ;
- isProduct(-) : the fact of being a product that is interpreted by the set $P \subset D$ ;
- isOrder(-) : the fact of being an order that is interpreted by the set $O \subset D$ ;
- CraftableProduct(-) that maps to products that can be manufactured (subset of $P$) ;
- AchievableOrder(-) that maps to orders that can be realised in the factory (subset of $O$) ;
- EknowsP(-,-) that maps to a subset of $(E \times P)$ interpreted as the fact that an employee knows how to craft a product ;
- OcontainsP(-,-) that maps to a subset of $(O \times P)$ interpreted as the fact that an order contains a product ;

We should now be able to state the two following axioms :

- (A1) $\forall x,y \in D, isProduct(x) \land isEmployee(y) \land EknowsP(y,x)$ 
  $\to CraftableProduct(x)$
- (A2) $\forall x,z \in D, CraftableProduct(x) \land isOrder(z) \land OcontainsP(z,x) \to AchievableOrder(z)$

From (A1) and (A2), we can derive the following theorem :

- (T) $\forall x,y,z \in D, isProduct(x) \land isEmployee(y) \land isOrder(z) \land EknowsP(y,x) \land OcontainsP(z,x) \to AchievableOrder(z)$

Now, if I have three constants $e,p,o$ respectively in $E,P,O$ such that $isProduct(p)$, $isEmployee(e)$, $isOrder(o)$, $EknowsP(e,p)$ and $OcontainsP(o,p)$ are true and if I feed the inference engine with (A1), (A2), (T), it should derive that $AchievableOrder(o)$ is true according to the axiomatic theory composed of (A1), (A2) and (T).

This is the end of my proposed answer to the initial question. I have also three extra questions :

- Do I really need predicates such as $isProduct(x)$ with $x \in D$ or could I choose to pick $x \in P$ and therefore assume that $isProduct(x)$ is true ?
- Is this theory alright even if my axioms are completely non sense with another interpretation ? My guess on this is that it is fine to use such theory as long as it is consistent.
- What should I modify in the above example if I would like to use some dynamic logic elements in the axioms ? As far as I understand things, I should extend the syntax with dynamic logic syntax, add dynamic logic axioms to the deductive system and extends the semantic with possible world models (even if I am not sure of how to do it...).

Thanks !

Comment: I think that at least the use of $\operatorname{isEmployee}(x)$ is necessary. For there micght be a constant $\text{ChuckNorris}$ with $\forall p\colon \operatorname{Eknows}(\text{ChuckNorris},p)$ and $\neg\operatorname{isEmployee}(\text{ChuckNorris})$, which would erroneously allow to deduce that $\forall o\colon \operatorname{AchievableOrder}(o)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assumed first-order logic. But if you use also $\in$ you are extending your language to first-order set theory.

Is this necessary ? I think not. In your axiom

> (A1) : $\forall x,y \in D (isProduct(x)\land isEmployee(y) ...$

you are using $\in D$ only to restrict the "applicability" of your axioms to the domain $D$: this is already given by your semantical interpretation.

You said : "Deductive system : an Hilbert system without logical axiom & modus ponens rule of inference ..."; you need logical axioms. It does not make sense an "Hilbert system" without them.

About the "three constants $e,p,o$  respectively in $E,P,O$  such that $isProduct(p)$ , etc. are true and if ...", the semantical "conventions" force us to assume that the domain $D$ is not empty. For predicates, in order to add to the language (syntactical part) some constants, you must prove that there are objects in the domain that are their *denotation*; in principle, the predicate may have as counterpart in the interpretation the $\emptyset$ subset of the domain $D$.

Having in the language a predicate $isProduct(p)$, does not assure you that exists in the domain at least an object that is a product. You have two choices: you must introduce axioms that give you *by fiat* the existence of those objects (like the axiom of set theory that introduce the *empty set*) and then you are allowed, by the rules of first-order logic, to add to your language the constants denoting them.

Otherwise, you introduce in the language *constants* for those objects (like $0$ in arithmetic) and the rule of standard semantics for first-order logic allows you to select "distinguished" objects in the domain that are the denotation of those constants in your interpretation.

*Question 1)* "Do I really need predicates such as $isProduct(x)$ with $x \in D$ or could I choose to pick $x \in P$ and therefore assume that $isProduct(x)$ is true ?"

As per comment about the domain $D$, you cannot mix the syntactical part (the language) with the semantical one (the interpretation of the language).

If you want to speak *in the language* of the objects $x$ of the domain $D$ such that they are "products" you must correctly introduce the predicate $isProduct(x)$ such that it holds of $x$ when $x$ is a product.

In the interpretation, the set $P$ will be exactly the interpretation of the predicate $isProduct(x)$, but $P$ will not be part of the language. So you need $isProduct(x)$.

*Question 2)* "Is this theory alright even if my axioms are completely non sense with another interpretation ? My guess on this is that it is fine to use such theory as long as it is consistent."

You are right. Formal arithmetic (that is first-order logic with Peano's axioms) is exactly f-o logic *plus* some non-logical axioms, like :

> $\forall x (\lnot 0 = S(x))$.

In "your" theory, this axioms is not true; strictly speaking, it is nonsense, because in your language their are no the $0$ and $S(x)$ symbols.

In the same way, your predicate $isProduct(x)$ is not parte of the language of arithmetic.

So, the conclusion is that natural numbers will not be a viable domain for an interpretation of your theory.